# Complex Rails Form Best Practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I've got a relatively complex form I'm trying to code efficiently.  Most online examples of nested forms deal with very clear hierarchical relationships, mine does not.

Below is the data model.  The essential job of the form is to create a "Job Entry" record while at the same time creating a new "Entity" record - which is a person.  Several relationships come to bear in this form.

A "Job" is already created.  The Job has 1-to-many "Questions" which exist before the user hits this form.  However, they must fill in "Answers" to the questions.  They also choose one of many pre-created "Job Roles".

[image: datamodel]

The question is how to leverage "form_with" and "fields_for" for all these inter-related models.

My assumption is to ditch built-in helpers and just use a form_tag and roll everything together manually.  But maybe there is a "correct" way to roll forms that do not necessarily abide by parent-child relationships? In my example, there is no pure top-level object to start with since many child objects already have records, but maybe I am wrong and Entity should be the starting point?

- Entity has_many Job_Roles
- Entity has_many Job_Entries
- Job has many Job_Roles
- Job has_many Job_Entries
- Job has_many Questions

  - Question has many Answers

    - Answers belong_to Entity
- Agency has_many Job_Entries
  etc...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to ditch the built-in helper: Rails has thought about that, it's called [nested forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms).

Here is an example:

```
<%= form_with model: @job do |f| %>
  Job entries:
  <ul>
    <%= f.fields_for :job_entries do |je_form| %>
      <li>
        <%= je_form.label :kind %>
        <%= je_form.text_field :kind %>
 
        <%= je_form.label :street %>
        <%= je_form.text_field :street %>
        ...
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

You can nest as many children forms as you'd like using fields_for. Don't forget to use **accepts_nested_attributes_for** in the parent models.

Comment: Oh I know all about nested forms and have tried many diff ways.  The issue here is that nested forms assumes parent-child-child, yes?

Comment: @ScottTallarida no i don't think they only accept parent-child-child forms. If you set accepts_nested_attributes_for to a parent (assuming belongs_to is defined), it should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Nested forms as Mike proposed are a rails-way solution of your problem. It is ok - but for complex forms, with lot of validations, it may not be the best solution). You could consider using a FormObject pattern instead.

FormObject is a simple ruby class that uou can keep it i.e. in `Forms` folder and use as below:

```
class JobEntryForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :customer_id, :agency_id, :name, :question_text #you can use atributes from different models

  validates :customer_id, presence: true #you can validate yu attributes as you want - your in necessity to use model validation

  def initialize(attributes:)
    @customer_id = attributes[:customer_id]
    @agency_id        = attributes[:agency_id]
    @name          = attributes[:name]
    @question_text = attributes[:question_text]
  end
  

  #implement whatever you need
end
```

than in you controller:
`@form = JobEntryForm.new`

and you your view:

```
<%= form_for @form do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :customer_id, 'Customer' %>:
  <%= f.text_field :customer_id %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And - at the end - in your controller create method:

```
def create
  @form = CreateJobEntry.new.call(attributes: form_params) #service object to keep your controller clean. 
end
```